# Colspan gridview expand more columns after clicking print button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have the below grid-view has 4 columns.

I have merged some columns in the footer.

The issue i am having after clicking `printbtn` the grid-view adds tow additional columns to the in the footer.

So the out put will be the original grid-view columns plus 2 empty columns in the grid-view footer.

**Grid-View**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" DataSourceID="SqlDs_Grid" OnRowDataBound="grid_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sr.No"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="Item Description" SortExpression="ProductName"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductQty" HeaderText="Quantity" SortExpression="ProductQty"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="UnitPrice" HeaderText="Unit Price"></asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total Amount" />
</Columns>
```

**Behind-Code**

```
protected void grid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
        {
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(1);
            e.Row.Cells.RemoveAt(2);
            e.Row.Cells[0].ColumnSpan = 3;
            e.Row.Cells[0].Text = "<div class='pull-left'>Total Amount In  Words </div> <br>" + "<div class='pull-left'>" + NumberToWords(Convert.ToInt32(Totalamount)) + "Only</div>";
            e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "Total Amount:";
            e.Row.Cells[2].Text = Totalamount.ToString();
        }
}
```

**Print Button**

```
<asp:Button ID="printbtn" runat="server" Text="Print" CssClass="btn btn-primary hidden-print" OnClientClick="javascript:window.print();" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens because the button click causes a postback. To prevent this, return `false` in the `OnClientClient` event:

```
<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="javascript:window.print(); return false;" />
```